# Java says this method has a constructor name

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I want to return the value of my array plus the return value of the recursive call.

However, for some reason, Java does not want to have the method name after the constructor.

In addition, when I tried to convert the method into another method, I get an error when I use isPalindrome.

I change my program around but I'm still getting errors.

```
public class isPalindrome {
    /**
     * This is the main entry point for the application
     * @return 
     */
    public static boolean main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] word = {"KayaK", "Desserts, I stressed"};

        
        
        boolean isPalindrome(String[] array, String s, String I) {
            
            if(i.charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
                System.out.println("You entered a Palindrome");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You didn't entered a Palindrome");
            }
        }
        
        
            try {
                System.in.read();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the array supposed to represent?  In main you use s for a string array, but isPalindrome does not appear to use the String array for anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't use the class name as the name for a method.  The only "methods" that can share a name with the class are constructors.

One fix would be to rename your class from `isPalindrome` to `PalindromeFinder` or something.  That would also better align with Java naming conventions.

EDIT: Note that you never actually called your method in main; you tryed to assign a local variable to `isPalindrome`.  That does not actually call the method.  You would need to invoke the method with `isPalindrome(...put your parameters here...)` and store the result in a variable with a name that isn't being used.

Also note that a method can only return a single value (a single primitive or a single object).  If you really want to return an array AND a boolean (and I'm not sure you do), you would have to store those in an object and return that object.

Comment: +1 - following the Java naming conventions will avoid this "problem" in its entirety/

Comment: I understand taht but how will i return my array

Comment: return isPalindrome(array, s.substring(1, s.length()-1)); is the problem

Comment: Would this work??

boolean isPalindrome = new boolean("true");

Boolean b = isPalindrome.booleanValue();

Comment: Lower case "boolean" is a primitive type, not an object.  Therefore you can't try to call a constructor by saying "new boolean(...)" and you can't try to invoke methods on them like "isPalindrome.booleanValue()".

Comment: @user516805 - that's not even remotely valid Java syntax.  And I can't see how it would help ... if it was.

Answer (score 0):

In java you cannot use the class' name as a variable name. The error tells you that only the constructor method of the class may have the same name of the class, and a constructor cannot return int (it does not return anything).

Comment: I understand taht but how will i return my array

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rename the class to Palindrome or PalindromeHelper

Comment: I understand that but how will i return my array

Comment: make the return type `boolean[]` instead of `boolean` I guess but I'm not sure about the parameters of that method.

Answer (score 0):

> but how will i return my array
>
> `return isPalindrome(array, s.substring(1, s.length()-1));` is the problem.

1. As written, nothing actually creates an array to be returned.  Hint: where is the `return new String[]...` or `return`array`?
2. Nothing modifies `array`, so there's no point returning it.
3. You can ... if it makes sense ... modify the array passed as an argument.
4. If you really do want to return an array from `isPalindrome`, you can't<sup>*</sup> also return `true` and `false`.  A method can only have one declared return type, and your code seems to "need" two; i.e. `String[]` and `boolean`.  Can't do that.

<sup>* OK you can ... by declaring the return type to be `Object`.  But that makes life difficult for the caller(s), and would be really bad design.</sup>